# Executando uma função em python tem como output "none"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu estou com um problema, eu tenho o seguinte código em Python.

```
def teste(n):
    n = int(n)
    if (n > 0) and (n < 200000):
        for i in range (1, n+1):
            if ((i % 3 == 0) and (i % 5 == 0)):
                print('FizzBuzz')
            elif ((i % 3 == 0) and (i % 5 != 0)):
                print('Fizz')
            elif ((i % 5 == 0) and (i % 3 != 0)):
                print('Buzz')
            elif ((i % 3 != 0) and (i % 5 != 0)):
                print(i)
    else:
        print('São aceitos apenas números entre 1 e 200000')

usuario = int(input('Olá, por favor digite o número: '))
resultado = teste(usuario)
print(resultado)
```

E quando o input é 5 por exemplo, o output é:

```
1   2   Fizz   4   Buzz  None
```

Minha pergunta é: por que esse `None` está aparecendo? E como corrigir isso?

Comment: Você mandou imprimir o que a função retorna. E como ela retorna `None`, é isso que foi impresso. Imprimir não é o mesmo que retornar.

Comment: A função não tem nenhum `return`, ou seja, ela não retorna nenhum valor. E quando a função não retorna nada, o Python assume que este retorno é `None`. Como ela não retorna nada, não faz sentido pegar o resultado dela e imprimir, então basta retirar o último `print` e só chamar a função. Ou seja, faça apenas `teste(usuario)`

Comment: Eu consegui corrigir, mas ainda não entendi porque quando eu uso o print tem como output none. Poderia me explicar melhor?

Comment: Ué, já foi explicado. Quando uma função não tem nenhum `return`, o Python faz com que o retorno dela seja `None`. No seu caso, a variável `resultado` recebe esse `None` que a função retorna, e o `print` mostra o valor dela, que é `None`. E como já dito, não faz sentido imprimir esse `resultado` se a função não retorna nada

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Aprece none pq o programa ta imprimindo as coisas de dentro da função e ao final do laço ele não tem nada para imprimir, por isso ele imprimi "nada", ou seja, none. Para resolver o problema eu sugiro fazer o seguinte.

Crie uma lista dentro da sua função e peça para adicionar os valores dentro da lista. ao final do laçor for peça para a função retornar a lista. Dessa forma o que será mostrado será a lista com todos os valores dentro.

```py
def teste(num):
  n = num
  lista = []
  if (n > 0) and (n < 200000):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
      if ((i % 3 == 0) and (i % 5 == 0)):
        lista.append('FizzBuzz')
      elif ((i % 3 == 0) and (i % 5 != 0)):
        lista.append('Fizz')
      elif ((i % 5 == 0) and (i % 3 != 0)):
        lista.append('Buzz')
      elif ((i % 3 != 0) and (i % 5 != 0)):
        lista.append(i)
    return lista
  else:
    return 'São aceitos apenas números entre 1 e 200000'


usuario = int(input('Olá, por favor digite o número: '))
resultado = teste(usuario)
print(resultado)
```